# How to draw outside the cell in TStringGrid.OnDrawCell?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I have a `TStringGrid` whose cells get a custom background color using the `OnDrawCell` event. Now I would like to visually extend each row to the right end of the grids `ClientRect`, i.e. remove the whitespace where there are no columns anymore.

I considered using an additional "phantom" column and constantly adjusting its `ColWidth`, but that hack doesn't work well with the grids somewhat awkward vertical scrolling behavior. My preferred solution would be to simply paint that area.

Calculating the relevant rect is easy, but what I paint to it gets erased instantly. I disabled `DefaultDrawing` and removed all of the options `goFixedVertLine`, `goFixedHorzLine`, `goVertLine` and `goHorzLine`, but to no effect.

Here's some sample code:

```
LGrid := TStringGrid(Sender);
LGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow + 1000 * (1 + ARow);
if ACol = LGrid.ColCount - 1 then
  Rect.Right := LGrid.ClientRect.Right; // Doesn't have any effect
LGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
```

What is the easiest way to achieve what the code above intended? I hope it is somehow possible to paint there without writing an interposer class, overriding the `Paint` method and implementing much of what is already available to me using this event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCL fills the empty area not occupied by cells after drawing of the cells are complete. That's why your painting gets over-drawn. It's possible to prevent what you paint getting erased instantly using the `OnDrawCell` event handler, no need to override `Paint` or derive a new control.

Since the VCL uses the same device context for drawing the cells and the empty area, you can clip out the extension rectangle you just drew from the device context, and the OS will disregard VCL's later painting calls for that zone.

```
LGrid := TStringGrid(Sender);
LGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow + 1000 * (1 + ARow);
if ACol = LGrid.ColCount - 1 then
  Rect.Right := LGrid.ClientRect.Right;
LGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
ExcludeClipRect(LGrid.Canvas.Handle, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);  // <--
```

Comment: While `ExcludeClipRect` certainly stops that area from being erased - I learned something :) - unfortunately the overall result is not as I hoped. The area that I can now successfully paint to does not get repainted when changing the selection or resizing. Perhaps in even more cases. Not sure if resolving that is in scope of this question, though.

Comment: @Thijs - OnDrawCell probably does not get called when resizing (enlarging empty area). In that case, I don't think it would be possible to contain intervention in OnDrawCell. I can't guess why selection is not working though...

Comment: To force repainting, you can use the `OnResize`, `OnSelectCell`, and `OnTopLeftChanged` events to manually `Invalidate()` the entire grid, or just `InvalidateRect()` the desired section(s).